# Getting a different value from a Hmac-sha256 online generator tool and Java Code

Tags: java, jackson, payload, hmacsha256

I would like to generate a signature from my Java code, this is my method:

```
public static String hmacWithJava(String algorithm, String data, String key)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), algorithm));
        String hexFormatSignature = "sha256=" + HexFormat.of().formatHex(mac.doFinal(data.getBytes()));
        return hexFormatSignature;
    }
```

where

```
   algorithm="HmacSHA256"`

    key="testKey";

    data="{
      "action" : "created",
      "installation" : {
        "id" : 2,
        "account" : {
          "login" : "testUser",
          "type" : "User"
        }
      },
      "sender" : {
        "login" : "testUser",
        "type" : "User"
      }
    }"

hexFormatSignature="sha256=11e20c46886a8e681fd2a3ad0e3a100d42579e1cf95417dd27acc80cedadabd5"
```

If I put the same payload in the https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online tool y got the next result: `"11e20c46886a8e681fd2a3ad0e3a100d42579e1cf95417dd27acc80cedadabd5"`

But this is not the correct signature, the correct one must be:`"aef0567d41bb28abe34d9202cd019668a8b35f65dd1981d22a74de5c19823b6a"`

The difference I have noticed is related with the json format, I mean the one generated from Jackson has less espaces o more enters that the one I am using manually and is generating the correct signature.

[image]

Left side is the one generated form Java code and right side the one that someone give me and its working.

This is the comparison between both text and they have the same values, but different indentation format, in fact if I add a space in the original payload I will have a different signature. Is there a way to solve this issue? Maybe I need to configure something to get the correct format from Java?

This is the manual payload, which is working:

```
{
  "action": "created",
   "installation" : {
       "id": 2,
        "account":{
            "login": "testUser",
            "type": "User"
         }
    },
    "sender" : {
        "login" : "testUser",
        "type" : "User"
    }
}
```

I am using Jackson to get the Json String from the Payload:

```
String jsonStr = obj.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(payload);
```

And my Payload object looks like this:

```
Payload{action='created', installation=model.Installation@3d121db3, sender=model.User@3b07a0d6}
```

Comment: You definitely will need the formatting to match perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way to do this not in a manual way?

Comment: Pick some super simple formatting rule: e.g. eliminate _all_ whitespace.

Comment: I have used the .stripIndent() method and the string is much similar, but not totally the same

Comment: What I was describing would be more like `.replaceAll("\s", "")`.

Comment: In this way I don not have any identation

Comment: Yes?  In this way you don't have to worry if the indentation is the same.

Comment: Yes.but the signature is generated wrong, in this case

Comment: Is it generated wrong when you do it on both sides?

Comment: Just from the one generated with the java code

Comment: Whatever you do, you're going to have to do it on both sides.  There is no way around that.

Comment: I cannot manipulate the manual postman json body, just the one that is generated un my code.

Comment: I mean, what it sounds like then is that you shouldn't be hashing the JSON string, but you should be hashing each individual JSON value.  That, or you're going to have to get exactly the same formatting.  If Jackson gives different formatting, then you can't use Jackson.  Or you could change how it's _hashed_ on the other side.  There's really nothing more anybody can tell you -- you've got to have it exactly the same, and it doesn't look like there's any reasonable automatic way to make the format match.